# An adjective or noun for one who cracks lame jokes

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, pejorative-language

Can someone please suggest an adjective or a noun to describe someone who always cracks 'lame jokes'? All I could think is 'Lame Joker' :/

I am specifically looking for a word/adjective that has negative connotations.

Thanks

Comment: Try [*paronomasiac*](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/paronomasiac) on for size.

Comment: @DanBron, Thanks. It kind of addresses the requirement but I am looking for something with more negative connotations. [Laughing Stock](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/laughing-stock) appears to be a better fit. Whats your opinion?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend *laughing stock* if only because it doesn't necessarily imply the person himself is *making jokes*, only that he's the butt of them. Why don't you add the detail that you're looking for a word with slightly negative connotations to the body of your questions, and I'll go and have another think about it.

Comment: I think you may be looking for **Father**.

Comment: My kids call them *Dad Jokes*. So the perpetrator would be a *Dad*.

Comment: If you're looking for a really old-time insult term, you could call him a "Joe Miller," after the guy associated with the 18th- and 19th-century [_Joe Miller's Complete Jest Book_](https://archive.org/stream/joemillerscomple00mill#page/n7/mode/2up). Sample comedic gold to be found therein (#1309): "An Irishman being told that a friend of his had put his money in the stocks. 'Well,; said he, 'I never had a farthing in the stocks, but I have had my legs often enough in them.'" Thank you, thank you. I'll be here all week.

Comment: **David Brent/ Michael Scott**, depending on which side of the pond your audience is.

Comment: Under some circumstances, that person is simply a **lamer**. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lamer Of the *real* dictionaries, Oxford sort of covers it: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/lamer

Comment: Obnoxious might fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"cornball"

NOUN: a person who tells "corny" jokes,
      a rube or bumpkin

"When it comes to telling jokes, he's a real cornball."

Oxford Dictionaries Online

"corny"

ADJECTIVE:  trite, banal, mawkishly sentimental

"His jokes are so corny."

Answer (score 1):

If your “lame joker” were here looking for a word to describe people who don’t like/get/appreciate his/her jokes, I’d perhaps suggest that they are “[humorless](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/humorless),” but since you got here first I’ll take you at your word that the jokes are lame and “stale or corny” enough to qualify as genuine “[groaners](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/groaner)” (Merriam-Webster) and suggest that this person could therefore be called a “[**Groan-meister**](http://h2g2.com/edited_entry/A3533609/conversation/view/F1995247/T606940).”

Comment: The word "groan-meister" itself kind of made me groan. ;)

Answer (score 0):

*[Nudnik](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nudnik?q=nudnick)*

> **OED**
>
> NOUN
>
> North American informal
>
> A pestering, nagging, or irritating person;
>
> ***a bore***.
>
> Origin
>
> 1940s: Yiddish, from Russian *nudnyĭ* '*tedious*'.NOUN

***Emphasis*** mine

Answer (score 0):

A **wag** is a person who can be counted on to make the obvious joke when opportunity arises. It may not be negative enough though, as it does imply  wittiness.